# Wordpress create post with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, insert

I want to make a custom PHP script, what can make a post for wordpress.

Here is my code from official page, but its not working:

```
require("wp-includes/post.php");

// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => "mytitle",
  'post_content'  => "mycontent",
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 1 )
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

**The error is:**

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_user_id() in
>   /home/MyUser/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 2897

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly what it says: you're making a call to a function that isn't available. So `function_get_user_id()` is never loaded.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation page you are using? I guess you are missing a file or some files which you need to require()

Comment: Are you doing this outside your WordPress-installation? You shouldnt need to include/require any WP-files.

Comment: This example from here:  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: the problem here is, that you simply run wordpress functions, while they not have been loaded, yet. hooks are your friends here, i.e. `add_action('init', 'your_function');` with that you can skip the require part, as wordpress takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are not logged in as a backend user. The script is trying to get a backend user id. There has to be a user logged in to create a post. Each post needs a userid, this is used to set the author of the post.

Also are you trying to execute this script inside a plugin or outside wordpress?

Comment: Im logged as admin (author ID=1), and this script is starting with session_start();

Answer (score 0):

For custom PHP script, just add the correct include "wp-load.php" instead of "post.php"

wp_insert_post() - return ID of new post [see more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

```
require('wp-load.php');
//require("wp-includes/post.php");

// Create post
$my_post = [
  'post_title'    => "mytitle",
  'post_content'  => "mycontent",
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => [ 1 ]
];

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```